# Extracting float from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, key

**Background -** 
I have a function that returns an API response. If `api_response` contains `meta` it will print the response, otherwise the function loops through some code that extracts and prints `id` and `percent_complete` key pair values. The purpose being is that the API response will return these values to show how close it is to having the data available for the user to call separately.

**Issue** - whilst the `id` is returned and printed without issue, the `percent_complete` returns blank.

**Function** -

```
def unpack_response():
    api_response = api_call()
# Code Block # 1
    while "meta" not in api_response:
        id_value = "id"
        res = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res = [val[percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val]
        percent_value = "".join(res)
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
# Code Block # 2
    if "meta" in api_response:
        print(api_response)
```

**Example print output** - an example showing what is currently printed every loop iteration:

```
Your data requested, associated with ID: 2205686 is  complete!
```

**API response** - example of response where I successfully extract the `id` key pair value, however where the `percent_complete` key pair value is blank:

```
{'data': {'id': '2205686',
  'type': 'jobs',
  'attributes': {'job_type': 'PORTFOLIO_VIEW_RESULTS',
   'started_at': '2021-12-16T18:59:50Z',
   'parameters': {'end_date': '2021-12-14',
    'output_type': 'json',
    'view_id': 304078,
    'portfolio_id': 1,
    'portfolio_type': 'firm',
    'start_date': '2021-12-14'},
   'percent_complete': 0.19,
   'status': 'In Progress'},
  'relationships': {'creator': {'links': {'self': '/v1/jobs/2205679/relationships/creator',
     'related': '/v1/jobs/2205679/creator'},
    'data': {'type': 'users', 'id': '731221'}}},
  'links': {'self': '/v1/jobs/2205679'}},
 'included': []}
```

**My thoughts** - unlike `id` (which has a key pair value in quotation marks) the `percent_complete` does not and is a float. Could my code require some changes to accommodate?

Comment: You need to be looking for `val['attributes']['percent_complete']`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried with both `res = [val['attributes']['percent_complete'] for key, val in api_response.items() if 'percent_complete' in val]' which uses the key values (rather than variables and `res = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val]`. Is there something else we're missing?

Comment: You also need it in the comparison at the end: `if percent_value in val['attributes']`

Comment: You could also use `get` with a default empty value to simplify it: `res = [val['attributes'].get(percent_value, '') for key, val in api_response.items()] (this will add empty items to the list, but they will 'disappear' after the `join`.

Comment: So I tried `res = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]` and get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, which points the line of code we've been working on. Why might that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the descried result as follows -

```
def unpack_response():
       api_response = api_call()
   # Code Block # 1
       while "meta" not in api_response:
           id_value = "id"
           res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
           id_value = "".join(res1)
           percent_value = "percent_complete"
   #         res2 = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]
           res2 = [val['attributes'].get(percent_value, '') for key, val in api_response.items()]
           percent_value = "".join(res2)
           print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')
           time.sleep(5)
           continue
   # Code Block # 2
       if "meta" in api_response:
           print(api_response)
   unpack_response()
```